# Handle Click Event Listener in Window Scroll Event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I applied window scroll event and then I am getting elements with document.querySelectorAll. So, After executing this i have NodeList. I am looping over this nodelist with forEach.
In forEach i am triggering click event on item. But my click event trigger multiple time. How I can handle it.

**Note:**
Run this code on vimeo home page.
https://vimeo.com/home

```
    window.addEventListener("scroll",()=>{
    var config = document.querySelectorAll("[data-config-url]");
  config.forEach((item)=>{
  item.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
  var configData = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-config-url");           
  console.log(configData);
  });
    });
 });
```

I want log configData of item for single time.

Comment: why do you add the listener for the click event every time the scroll event gets hit? you will end having multiple handlers for the same event to the same elements.. am I wrong? and by the way `document.querySelectorAll("[data-config-url]").length` returns zero on vimeo homepage.

Comment: I just want to know when the new item is added into the viewPort, basically the idea is I want to apply click on every document's "data-config-url" and for that I have added listener on scroll

Comment: Is there any way so that I can get only the specific doucment added into the current ViewPort, also one more lag here is I'm quering all the docuemnts every time and I want to get rid of it and only get the document which don't have click on that specific element. I have wrote a function to handle this but failed to do this.

Comment: I didn't hit the scenario when there are available elements you are willing to target there... anyway to accomplish what you wish, you could have a routine running every once in a while (with setInterval) that will fetch all available elements, and for each one will check first if the click handler was added (for example adding a data attribute to the element as a flag stating it was already processed the first time you added the handler) before trying to add the handler to it.

Comment: Kindly apply this script on mobile view.

Comment: create the click listener only if it does not exist already. In this way, we can avoid multiple listener problems. 
OR
Remove the listener as soon as item is removed on scroll up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on my comments above, I couldn't hit the scenario you described at the url https://vimeo.com/home. Not even when adopting the mobile screen simulation. I'm using Firefox 101.0.1 (64 bit) on Windows 10 in this moment.

`document.querySelectorAll("[data-config-url]").length` always returns zero and that's true also after trying to navigate the page, scrolling, opening menu blocks and so on. I didn't login because I don't have an account and you didn't specify how the page is supposed to be visited beyond the url itself.

Anyway when the scenario gets hit, that's the code implementing the logic I suggested in my comments. I just slightly modified your code so that the handler gets added only if the element wasn't already processed previously.

It then repeats the operation once every 500ms:

```js
setInterval(scanPageAndAddHandlers, 500);

function scanPageAndAddHandlers(){
  console.log('scanning...');
  var config = document.querySelectorAll("[data-config-url]");
  config.forEach((item)=>{
    if (item.dataset.handlerWasAdded != 'true'){
      //add the listener for the click event to the item element
      item.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
        var configData = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-config-url");           
        console.log(configData);
      });          
      //mark this item as processed
      item.dataset.handlerWasAdded = 'true';
    }    
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks "Diego De Vita" it works. !!!

Comment: I'm glad.. I hope the setInterval approach isn't too much... feel free to try other approaches.. maybe also your scroll idea wasn't bad... maybe made more sense because the page doesn't update its content if your staying still. Anyway the key part was just the way to discern when to add or not the click event handler and my suggestion using a data attribute flag was one of many. Glad it helped